# Capturing which left hand item in the null-coalescing operator successfully assigned variable

Tags: c#

I'm using the `??` operator to try and assign an object based on the best match found in a list.

I have various matching rules but have simplified this for the example:

```
objectImTryingToSet =
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking numerous things*/) ??                  //rule1
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking different numerous things*/) ??        //rule2
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking again different numerous things*/);    //rule3
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to store a string logging which rule was the one which successfully assigned `objectImTryingToSet` as I have a bug wherby in one scenario the object is being assigned when it shouldn't be and its a real headache manually trying to sift through all these rules to find out where the incorrect assignment lies.

So I basically want, pseudo:

```
string ruleThatMatched = null;

objectImTryingToSet =
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking numerous things*/) ??  if (objectImTryingToSet != null) { ruleThatMatched = "rule1" }                 //rule1
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking different numerous things*/) ??  if (objectImTryingToSet != null) { ruleThatMatched = "rule2" }       //rule2
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking again different numerous things*/); if (objectImTryingToSet != null) { ruleThatMatched = "rule3"}     //rule3

//tried all the rules and still no match
if (objectImTryingToSet == null)
{
    ruleThatMatched = "no rule managed to find a match";
}
```

Is this even possible using the `??` operator?

Comment: Why don't you use an `if...else`?

Comment: when you're using ternary or null-coalescing operator and it starts getting this complicated, you are much better off switching to an if/else or switch.

Comment: "Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*!" "Stop doing that." ...Sorry, couldn't resist. :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was to begin with but it got very messy as I have 10 different rules, which is going to continue growing as testing brings back more information on how to successfully match, I refactored to use the null-coalescing operator to make it easier to read, as a worst case scenario I will revert back to if...else but I would prefer to handle it like this if at all possible. I thought it was worth asking on SO before I go back to how it was.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what the actual problem is.  You gave us a vague explanation of `"I have a bug wherby in one scenario the object is being assigned when it shouldn't be"`.

Comment: If the number of rules is growing, it's probably worth considering a different model entirely, as neither conditional construct is going to yield readable code. For example, you could capture the logic for each rule in a type, and iterate through a collection of rules. This is a common validation pattern.

Comment: There is no problem as such, I know I can accomplish what I want using if...else, the bug is irrelevant, I just want to know if I can somehow store which left hand "rule" successfully matched using the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: I think that you should start using `if/else` rather than using ternary operators and null coalessing operators for business logic, but, if you're dead set on that, are you trying to do something like `objectImTryingToSet = objectImTryingToSet ?? (/*other stuff*/)`?

Comment: Refactoring to use a Rule model sounds like the best bet, anyone got an example or some basic code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var res =
    MyListOfPotentialMatches.Select(v => new {r=1, v}).FirstOrDefault(/*lamda checking numerous things*/) ??
    MyListOfPotentialMatches.Select(v => new {r=2, v}).FirstOrDefault(/*lamda checking different numerous things*/) ??
    MyListOfPotentialMatches.Select(v => new {r=3, v}).FirstOrDefault(/*lamda checking again different numerous things*/);
if (res != null) {
    var ruleNumber = res.r;
    objectImTryingToSet = res.v;
}
```

The key is `Select` which pairs up the result with a hard-coded rule number.

Note that you could do it without `??` operator, too:

```
var firstChoice = MyListOfPotentialMatches.Select(v => new {r=1, v}).Where(/*lamda checking numerous things*/);
var secondChoice = MyListOfPotentialMatches.Select(v => new {r=2, v}).Where(/*lamda checking different numerous things*/);
var thirdChoice = MyListOfPotentialMatches.Select(v => new {r=3, v}).Where(/*lamda checking again different numerous things*/);
var res = firstChoice.Concat(secondChoice).Concat(thirdChoice).FirstOrDefault();
if (res != null) {
    var ruleNumber = res.r;
    objectImTryingToSet = res.v;
}
```

Comment: so is this using Anonymous Types to add a read only property to v ?

Comment: @SelectDistinct Yes, that's what it does.

Comment: Im getting "Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'MySolution.Core.AddressService.JsonAddressModel' " the first rule looks like this for info: Addresses.Select(v => new { r = 1, v }).FirstOrDefault(v => v.v.paon.Trim() == exception.AddressLineOne && v.v.dthorofare.Trim() == exception.AddressLineTwo);

Comment: @SelectDistinct This says that somewhere there's an attempt to assign the result of this query to a `JsonAddressModel `  variable without taking the `v` component. The result needs to be assigned to a `var` first, then you check `r`, and then take `v` for further use.

Comment: @SelectDistinct It's not the first rule, it's either what it is being assigned to (i.e. `objectImTryingToSet`) or the right-hand side of `??`.

Comment: sorted that now thanks, but now getting Error 1 Operator '??' cannot be applied to operands of type 'AnonymousType#1' and 'MySolution.Core.AddressService.JsonAddressModel'

Comment: @SelectDistinct The new error says that you probably have not converted the second or the third rule to use anonymous types yet.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, so everyone who recommended I should revert to using if...else statements might not have suggested this approach for a valid reason but I cant see what's wrong with this.

Answer (score 2):

(Edited so that it looks closer to your pseudo code, but you'll have to fill in some blanks, because I don't know the type of your object)

```
string ruleThatMatched = null;
Func<string, TypeOfObjectImTryingToSet, TypeOfObjectImTryingToSet> getAndTrackRule =
    (ruleText, obj) =>
        {
            ruleThatMatched = ruleText;
            return obj;
        };


var objectImTryingToSet =
    getAndTrackRule("rule1", MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking numerous things*/)) ??
    getAndTrackRule("rule2", MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking different numerous things*/)) ??
    getAndTrackRule("rule3", MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(*/lamda checking again different numerous things*/));

if (objectImTryingToSet == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("no rule managed to find a match");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Final value {0} found by applying rule {1}", objectImTryingToSet, ruleThatMatched));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a custom Extension method that wraps up your kind of logic.  It's not pretty, but you can call this instead of the standard `FirstOrDefault`.  It takes an extra `string` as an `out` parameter, and another `string` as the debugging message you want.

```
public static T GetFirstWithMessage<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
                                       Func<T, bool> matchFunc, 
                                       out string outputString, 
                                       string message) 
{
    var match = collection.FirstOrDefault(matchFunc);
    outputString = match == null ? null : message;
    return match;
}
```

Then you can chain these together with something like this.

```
string matchedRule;

var matchedFruit = fruits.GetFirstWithMessage(f => f.Count < 1, out matchedRule, "Out of stock")
    ?? fruits.GetFirstWithMessage(f => f.Name.Length > 10, out  matchedRule, "Long name")
    ?? fruits.GetFirstWithMessage(f => !f.IsFresh, out  matchedRule, "Rotten Fruit")
    ?? fruits.GetFirstWithMessage(f => f.Count > 24, out  matchedRule, "Big group");
```

[A demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wmpvcx)

Comment: @SelectDistinct this is nice !!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int?> intList = new List<int?>() { 3, 4};


    Func<int?, bool> rule = null;

    var value = intList.FirstOrDefault(rule = (i => i == 1)) 
             ?? intList.FirstOrDefault(rule = (i => i == 2)) 
             ?? intList.FirstOrDefault(rule = (i => i == 3)) 
             ?? intList.FirstOrDefault(rule = (i => i == 4));
}
```

As a note, this is only for exploring what you can do with the language.  I wouldn't recommend actually doing this in production code.  This is harder to read than it needs to be.

---

Here's another approach you can take

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int?> intList = new List<int?>() { 3, 4};

        List<RuleModel> Rules = new List<RuleModel>();

        Rules.Add(new RuleModel{Name = "Rule1", Rule = (i => i == 1)});
        Rules.Add(new RuleModel{Name = "Rule2", Rule = (i => i == 2)});
        Rules.Add(new RuleModel{Name = "Rule3", Rule = (i => i == 3)});
        Rules.Add(new RuleModel{Name = "Rule4", Rule = (i => i == 4)});

        int? valueToSet = null;

        var ruleUsed = Rules.FirstOrDefault(r => (valueToSet = intList.FirstOrDefault(r.Rule)) != null);
    }

}

public class RuleModel
{
    public Func<int?, bool> Rule { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create 3 checking functions with **out** argument.

```
function bool check1(YourObject obj, out string ruleMatched)
{
    ruleMatched = "rule1";
    return /* checking numerous things */;
}

// same for each checking

string ruleMatched;
objectImTryingToSet =
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(x => check1(x, out ruleMatched)) ?? //rule1
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(x => check2(x, out ruleMatched)) ?? //rule2
MyListOfPotentialMatches.FirstOrDefault(x => check3(x, out ruleMatched)); //rule3
```

Comment: So your suggesting rolling each rule into a method?

Comment: @SelectDistinct yes, it will add more readability and reusability.